# JavaScript WebSocket. Можно ли заставить работать(хотя бы в Firefox и Chrome) WebSocket с HTTPS странцы на HTTP?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Сайт на HTTPS но с него нужно выполнить запрос на HTTP. Можно ли это как то задекларировать в браузере чтобы сработало(хотя бы для Firefox и Chrome)?
То есть если wss прописываю в New Websocket в качестве протокола, то всё нормально если ws, то выполнение скрипта после этой строчки обрывается.

И соответственно если загрузить страницу сайта по HTTP то и с ws работает.

Comment: Нет, нельзя (еще символы)

Answer (score 0):

В современных браузерах запрещено использование ws со страницы https, т.к. это нарушение безопасности. На сколько знаю, настройками страницы этот вопрос не решается. Обойти можно реализовав прокси wss <-> ws на стороне сервера. Например для nginx что-то вроде:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/cert.key;

  location /3rdpartyproxy {
    proxy_pass http://3rdparty_url_or_ip;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
    proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
  }
}
```

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/518923)

Comment: @Victor VosMottor в ответе дана полная информация и в добавок вариант решения. так что не надо писать ерунду.